# How to prove $\frac{7n^2 +5n}{3n^2-7}$ is convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Prove the following converges:

$$\displaystyle \lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{7n^2 +5n}{3n^2-7} = \frac{7}{3}$$

Proposed Solution:

Given $\varepsilon$ > 0, find a M $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\frac{1}{M}$ < $\varepsilon$. Then for all n $\geq$ M.

$$\mid \frac{7n^2 + 5n}{3n^2 - 7} - \frac{7}{3}\mid = \mid \frac{7n^2 + 5n - 7n^2 - 7}{3n^2 - 7} \mid = \mid \frac{5n - 7}{3n^2 - 7}\mid$$
How do  I show that this is less than $\frac{1}{M}$ and $\varepsilon$ and connect it to $\frac{7}{3}$ ?

Thanks for your help folks.

Comment: Your fraction subtraction does not look correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fraction subtraction does not look correct.

$|\frac{7n^2 + 5n}{3n^2 - 7} - \frac{7}{3}| = |\frac{21n^2 + 15n - 21n^2 + 49}{3(3n^2 - 7)}| = |\frac{15n + 49}{3(3n^2 - 7)}|$

While $\frac {5n - \alpha}{3n^2-7} > \frac {5}{3n}$ it is not much greater when n is large.  But, the easy thing to do is pick a relatively value of n. i.e. $n=3$

$f(3) - \frac {7}{3} = \frac {47}{30}$

$n\ge 3 \implies |f(n) - \frac 73| < \frac {5}{n}$

Why 5? just because it is round, it is not really important.  If you feel the need to work out the inequality and that it indeed holds, then go for it.

For any $\epsilon > 0,$ when $N = \max (3, \frac {5}{\epsilon})$ then $n>N \implies |f(n) - \frac {7}{3}| < \epsilon.$

Answer (score 4):

Write

$$\frac{7n^2+5n}{3n^2-7}=\frac{7+5/n}{3-7/n^2},$$

and use the fact that $\lim_{n\uparrow \infty }\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{\lim_{n\uparrow \infty }a_n}{\lim_{n\uparrow \infty }b_n}$ if $\lim_{n\uparrow \infty }b_n\neq 0.$

Comment: I've never seen this notation before, why not just write $n\to\infty$?

Comment: @Snaw Meh, I prefer it because it takes up less horizontal space; and as for its use: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124489/limits-notation

Answer (score 1):

Note that if
$p(n)$ and $q(n)$
are polynomials of degree
at most $d-1$
and
$a, b \ne 0$ then

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{an^d+p(n)}{bn^d+q(n)}-\dfrac{a}{b}
&=\dfrac{b(an^d+p(n))-a(bn^d+q(n))}{b(bn^d+q(n))}\\
&=\dfrac{bp(n)-aq(n)}{b(bn^d+q(n))}\\
&\to 0
\text{ as } n\to \infty\\
\end{array}
$

since the numerator is of degree
at most $d-1$
and the denominator is of
exact degree $d$.

Therefore
$\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{an^d+p(n)}{bn^d+q(n)}
=\dfrac{a}{b}
$.